# what is the best way to format dates for MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, formatting, etl

when inserting data into MySQL and dates are not in an agreeable SQL format like `yyyy-mm-dd`, what approach do you take to correct this column?

usually i write a custom ETL script to handle date formatting as data is being inserted, but i'm wondering if there a quicker and easier method? like something i could just do in mysql after the data is loaded?

for example, i have different files each with different date formats...

```
2013 Mar 05 23:26:32 
01/03/2015
01/03/2015 23:26:32
```

annoying right?

Comment: Have you looked at the STR_TO_DATE function : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: i'd, tried this but i get null on convertDate column? however, when i try it on a string it converts... SELECT 
date,
STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y %m,%d') as convertDate
FROM table

Comment: ok, figured out what i was doing wrong. cheers PaulF

Answer (score 0):

> when inserting data into MySQL and dates are not in an agreeable SQL format like yyyy-mm-dd, what approach do you take to correct this column?

1. Parse the dates on the client.
2. Pass the date as an object of type date.
3. Repeat for *all* the values I'm adding according to the required type in each case.

This has two benefits:

- I don't need to know what format the database engine requires (which could be dependent on the locale the server happens to be using).
- I don't need to worry about quoting of those values to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Summary: database clients understand how to send typed data to their database: make use of that functionality rather than re-creating it.

Comment: richard... was your answer some type of riddle, like in the film batman where the penguin can only answer questions with a riddle?

Comment: @user3768071 Perhaps I am assuming too much, but you must be using some type of client to the database, an (unless you are building everything by hand in SQL Workbench) the client will do that SQL statement building for you. So have it build parametrised queries.